# Error Old route in Symfony2 (server)

Tags: git, symfony

I change the route "wall-last" to "wall_last", then i update my server with github

I empty cache with all command symfony2 and also rm -r cache

but when i test on my server i receive this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException' with message 'Unable to generate a URL for the named route "wall-last" as such route does not exist.' in /www/htdocs/my.site.com/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlGenerator.php:196 Stack trace: #0 /www/htdocs/my.site.com/app/cache/prod/classes.php(6253): appProdUrlGenerator->generate('wall-last', Array, false) #1 /www/htdocs/my.site.com/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/RoutingExtension.php(45): JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\Router\I18nRouter->generate('wall-last', Array, false) #2 /www/htdocs/my.site.com/app/cache/prod/twig/ce/14/d78e2a16c35929217734752bfba0c0988cb9a5fb22b1117f556e5d510d15.php(171): Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension->getPath('wall-last') #3 /www/htdocs/my.site.com/app/cache/prod/classes.php(4357): __TwigTemplate_ce14d78e2a16c35929217734752bfba0c0988cb9a5fb22b1117f556e5d510d15->block_content(Array, Array) #4 /www/htdocs/my.site.com/app/cache/prod/twig/1b/50/ebd9771273fa32 in /www/htdocs/my.site.com/app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 4361
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep for 'wall-last'. Looks like you generate pathes with 'wall-last' route somewhere in your code